# first 500 from 1300 and do something with it

Tags: php

Lets say we have 1300 units. now i want to first 500 units to be a price of 12 euro and the other 800 a price of 9 euro.

So what i basicly need is a function that calculates over a total number and gets the first 500 * 12 euro and the other 800 * 9 euro. But the total unit can also be 5000 instead of this example of 1300 unit, its user input ofcouse.

```
<?php

$total = 1300;
$sub = 1;
$sub2 = 1;

for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++)
{
    for($sub; $i<=500; $sub++)
    {
        $sub2 += $sub;
        break;      
    }       
}

echo $sub2;


?>
```

Comment: With reading your comments on questions. It's clear you need to add more information into your question, showing how you're trying to work out this mathematical problem, show intended results and actual results for the best response from the community

Comment: You are changing your multiplication number dynamically. How would you implement a changing variable which starts at 12 for 500 then 9 with 800?

Comment: it has to be 500 * 12 euro and 800 * 9 euro

Comment: And then the instances after? Or is it just the two?

Comment: The first 500 has a price of 12 euro and everything after that a price of 9 euro

Comment: @Dagon Hit it on the head

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$units = 1300;
$cut_off=500;//made it a var just in case
$a=12;//fist 500
$b=9;//rest

//verbose calculations, you don't really need to create the extra variables
$a_total=$cut_off*$a;
$b_total=($units-$cut_off)*$b;

$grand_total=$a_total+$b_total;

?>
```

you should probably add a check if the units imputed is less than 500. or things will turn out weird

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

```
<?php
    function calc_total($qtt, $min = 500, $fst_price = 12, $nxt_price = 9){

        if($qtt > $min) return false; // Check if the minimum 500 was sent.

        /* First calculate the rest, which is the quantity sent by 
        the user without the minimum x 9. Then add the minimum x 12 */

        $total = (($qtt - $min) * 9) + ($min * 12);

        return $total;

    }
?>
```

You can call the function like this:

```
 echo "$". calc_total(1300);
```

Comment: okey but that gets me 1,2,3,4,5 - 500. but i need 1 number. for example 500 * 11 and 800 * 9

Comment: Sorry I really don't think I understood the question, or maybe no one did. Try explaining what's your goal with this, like a little deeper. It doesn't seem like a difficult issue, but we need to understand it. =D

Comment: I updated the answer, check it if it solves your problem.